# Deleting everything inside table and replacing it - sqlite

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite

Here's my problem...I have some code here:

```
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
               var optgroup = String($('#myselect').val());

               var optarray = optgroup.split(',');
               for(var i=0; i<optarray.length; i++){
               transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO table1(colum1)\
                                      VALUES(?)',[optarray[i]],
                                      nullHandler);
               }

               });
```

This in itself isn't a problem, it works as expected.  Each value from the array is stored in a different row of the table.  My problem is that I want to update the table if the user selects different values from myselect.

If I do INSERT OR REPLACE then obviously, while iterating through the array it will only put the last value into a single row.  Is there a way to delete everything inside the table and then store the new values?  I basically want a system whereby I can get rid of the previous rows that the user made and put in new ones based on the new input a user makes.

I'm really struggling to wrap my head around how to do this.

Comment: Are you asking about [`DELETE`](http://sqlite.org/lang_delete.html)?

Comment: Yeah, realised 5 minutes after posting this that all I needed was a delete query before the insert query

Comment: I sometimes have the impression that SQL is the new JavaScript. Lots of coders think it's a minor and uninteresting language (or even consider it a feature of PHP) and `SELECT * FROM mytable` is all you'll ever need to know. Well, glad you got it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised it was actually really simple, I guess I just forgot about the DELETE query >.<

```
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
               transaction.executeSql('DELETE FROM table1 WHERE Id > 0\
                                      ',
                                      nullHandler);


               });

db.transaction(function(transaction) {
           var optgroup = String($('#myselect').val());

           var optarray = optgroup.split(',');
           for(var i=0; i<optarray.length; i++){
           transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO table1(colum1)\
                                  VALUES(?)',[optarray[i]],
                                  nullHandler);
           }

           });
```

So before inserting the new values, it deletes everything inside the table first.  This works fine.